# Parameter sensitivity when integrating in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, lazy-computations

When I try to integrate this MMA freezes:

```
II = (A^2 Sin[θ] (-R Cos[θ]^2 + Cos[θ] (ρx + ρz - R Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ]) + Sin[θ] (-2 R Cos[ϕ]^2 Sin[θ] + Cos[ϕ] (2 ρx - R Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ]) + Sin[ϕ] (ρx + ρy - R Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ]))))/((ρz - R Cos[θ])^2 + (ρx - R Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ])^2 + (ρy - R Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ])^2)^(3/2)
```

```
Integrate[II, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, {θ, 0, π},Assumptions -> {R > 
   0, ρy ∈ Reals && ρx ∈ 
    Reals && ρz ∈ Reals && R ∈ Reals && 
   R > 0 && θ ∈ Reals && 0 < θ < π && 
   0 < ϕ < 2 π && ϕ ∈ Reals && 
   A > 0 && ρz > 0 && ρz < R && ρy < R && ρx < R}]
```

But if I impose `ρz=0` the integral is very quickly solved. Any suggestions to why this happens and how to encourage MMA to find a useful substitution?

Comment: What's known about `R , ρx,ρy,ρx,A`?

Comment: I have imposed those conditions actually, see edited version of the question.

Comment: Not really unfortunately...